# find condition issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

min_age = params[:min_age]

max_age = params[:max_age]

@users = User.find(:all,
                      :conditions => [" years >= ? AND years <= ? ",  min_age, max_age])

This is the controller method for a search feature.  As you can see I wish to search by age range.  This works for all max_age values up to 99, but when the max_age exceeds 99 the search returns no results when it should.  I don't really expect many people beyond 99 but I am curious why this is happening.  The age is a string.

Comment: it's a string (varchar) in the db schema or in ruby code?

Answer (score 3):

It's because "100" comes before "20" when you compare *alphanumerically* as strings do. Change `age` to an integer as it should be, and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Mark Byers has the right answer. So it should be accepted.

But you should know, this is the kind of thing you should be using a [named scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html) for.

In user.rb

```
named_scope :ages_in_range, lambda {|min, max|
  {:conditions => ["years >= ? AND years <= ?", min, max]}
}
```

Now in your controller:

```
@users = User.ages_in_range(min_age,max_age)
```